# Найти среднее геометрическое элементов в столбике, что содержит минимальный элемент матрицы

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пишу программу на с++ и не понимаю как найти среднее геометрическое только для одного столбца, в котором расположен минимальный элемент массива размером n на m.

```
    int main()
{
srand((unsigned)time(0));
const int n = 5;
const int m = 8;
int A[n][m];
int i;
int j;
cout << "array: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
        A[i][j] = rand() % 80;
        cout.width(5);
        cout << A[i][j];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int min = A[0][0];
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        if (A[i][j] < min){
            min = A[i][j];
        }
}
cout << "Min element " << min << endl;
```

}

Comment: Вам нужно запоминать _индекс_ столбца с минимумом, а не просто искать минимум.  После этого вычисляете [среднее геометрическое](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5) Но не совсем понятно, что нужно вычислять, если окажется несколько столбцов, содержащих минимум.

Answer (score 0):

Как абсолютно правильно написал @NowhereMan вам нужно при поиске минимума запоминать столбец, в котором этот минимум находится.

```
        if (A[i][j] < min){
            min = A[i][j];
            colNum = j;
        }
```

Поскольку среднее геометрическое вычисляется только для положительных чисел, то массив можно делать типа `unsigned`.
Также у вас тут возможная логическая ошибка - вероятнее всего ноль не должен участвовать в расчетах, т.к. ноль как особое число не имеет знака и поэтому не считается положительным. Хотя формально `0` не нарушает формулу - корень любой степени из ноля будет ноль. Если убрать ноль то будет как-то так:

```
A[i][j] = rand() % 80 + 1; // генерятся числа от 1 до 80
```

Кроме того, чтобы дважды не делать перебор всего массива, поиск минимума можно выполнять сразу при заполнении.

```
   int min = INT_MAX;
....
   {
        A[i][j] = rand() % 80; // генерятся числа от 0 до 79
        if (A[i][j] < min){
            min = A[i][j];
            colNum = j;
        }
   }
```

После выполнения цикла, у вас известен номер столбца, в котором находится минимальный элемент - `colNum`. Но если у вас несколько одинаковых минимальных элементов, то здесь запомнится первый из них. Вы сами должны определить логику - как действовать, если минимальных элементов несколько в разных столбцах.
Проходите циклом по этому столбцу и ищете среднее геометрическое.

```
double average = 1.0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   average *= A[i][colNum]; // произведение всех чисел столбца
```

Поскольку у вас умножение, при больших `n` возможно переполнение переменной `average`!

Comment: И не забудьте потом вычислить корень n-й степени из произведения...